# Android Socket Realtime Reading

Tags: android, sockets, kotlin, client-server, real-time

I am in a situation of Fast Server Slow Client. My server sends the data at a rate of 38200 bytes per seconds 
Here is the client side code:

socket

```
socket = Socket(connectionId.getAddress(), 2500)
    socket?.soTimeout = 5000
    val receiveBufferSize = socket?.receiveBufferSize
    Log.d(TAG, "Buffer size $receiveBufferSize")
    socket?.receiveBufferSize = 382

    bufferedReader = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(inputStream), 382)
```

NOTE: As you can see, I have tried to limit the size of the buffer of both the socket and the reader.

reading:

```
try {
            do {
                val line = bufferedReader?.readLine()
                line?.let {
                    listener?.serialDataReceived(it + "\r\n")
                }
            } while (line != null)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to read from $TAG", e)
        }
```

The issue is my client reads staled data, which was valid 10 seconds ago

I would like to find a way of reading only the latest data and ignore the one buffered by my reader.

What should I do?

thank you

Comment: What is the point of the bizarre 382 byte buffer sizes?

Comment: I wanted to force the buffer to only store the last data packet which is 382 bytes in size.

Comment: Tcp doesn't have data packets whose size you can count on. But why limit the size to so small a buffer? It will only cause the TCP to slow the transmission rate.

Comment: It would be more to the point to use an *enormous* buffer size and read from it as quickly as possible, discarding all but the most recent message, noting that message recognition is completely up to you as TCP is only a byte-stream protocol. There is no way to get TCP to throw away data.

Comment: How can read only most recent data? Is there a way to read from a BufferedReader starting from the end?